# Mapping Jason-3 Data in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, netcdf, satellite

Has anyone figured out an easy way to convert [Jason-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason-3) data in NetCDF format to a GIS format (raster, shapefile, etc.) so it can be viewed in ArcGIS Desktop?

Jason-3 data is available for free in NetCDF format, but despite several attempts I have been unable to convert the lat and long data to a mappable format.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the most effective way to work with Jason data is via this application: http://www.altimetry.info/toolbox/ It provides a means to process and visualize altimetry data from a variety of different sources.